A movie about egypt pyramid's and human creation
There's a group. They are studying old civilizations.
As I remember they go to Egypt and study pyramid's and they see there are some signs and paintings in every civilization that they mention about a star (a star between 2 stars).
(BTW that's SCI-FI movie)
They have advanced tools and science so they go to that star and they saw
there is another big planet , bigger than earth. They are the creators of human and made humans and sent them to earth. They study and study and reach a clue about their creators.
Hope you guys can help me identify this movie.

You are looking for Prometheus from 2012: 

In 2089, archaeologists Elizabeth Shaw and Charlie Holloway discover a star map in Scotland that matches others from several unconnected ancient cultures. They interpret this as an invitation from humanity's forerunners, the "Engineers". 

You can see one of the star maps here:


@a-j Oh, can't believe.Thanks <3

@IlgarDadashi Please mark the question as answered
